# Is there a shorter way to parse attributes as Int (or any other primitive) in LinqToSql

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

I was basically wondering if it is possible to optimize this code:

```
AmountComments = Int32.Parse(r.Attribute("AmountComments").Value)
```

Ideally I would want to write something like

```
AmountComments = r.Attribute("AmountComments")
```

*r* would be a xml tag of type XElement, which is selected before in a Linq query.

Comment: I guess Value is a string, so Parse is the way to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider writing an extension method(s) for the type of `.Attribute()`

One extension method for each type that you'd like out. This way you'd simply be able to:

```
AmountComments = r.Attribute("AmountComments").ToInt32();


public static class LinqUtils
{
    public static int Int32(this XAttribute attribute)
    {
        return System.Int32.Parse(attribute.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Tomh - Cheers, was just filling in the extension method myself when I got the orange popup bar saying you'd edited the answer. Good edit!